# SQL Server - Update a table with text file

Tags: sql-server

I have a table stored in database with below sample data:

```
  Name     City     Age
  lily   New York   NULL
  Sam    Seattle    NULL
```

Now I need to update the table with a text file containing below data:

```
  Name     City     Age
  lily   New York   27
  Sam    Seattle    33
```

The text file comes without the column names.
I'm not allowed to drop the current table and do a bulk insert with the new text file. Anyone knows the way around it? Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql Server Management Studio => Right Click on the Destination Database => Tasks => Import Data

there you will have a wizard, you can choose "flat file" as a source

i don't remember if you can script that before executing it

Comment: When I use the import function, it is trying to add all rows again which is not waht wanted as only column Age need to be added. Could you please direct me on how to change the seetings to achieve that? Very much appreciated!

Comment: did you configure the mappings specifying which is the primary key? it should go on update automatically

Answer (score 1):

You could create a linked Server with OLEDB-Provider for Jet-Engine with Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited